# Spring physics applied to quaternions using python

Tags: python, numpy, physics, quaternions

I want to create a simple physics system in python that works on `quaternions` in a similar fashion as `velocity/position`. Its main goal is to simulate one object being dragged and try to catch up to another over time. The simulation uses 3 variables: `k`: the spring constant, `d`: a dampening factor, and `m`: the mass of the dragged object.

Using classic euler integration I can solve the positions with:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

# init simulation values
dt = 1./30. # delta t @ 30fps
k = 0.5 # Spring constant
d = 0.1 # Damping
m = 0.1 # Mass

p_ = np.array([0,0,0]) # initial position of the dragged object
p  = np.array([1,2,0]) # position to catch up to, in real life this value could change over time
v  = np.array([0,0,0]) # velocity buffer (init speed is assumed to be 0)

# Euler Integration
n = 200 # loop over 200 times just to see the values converge
for i in xrange(n):
    x  = (p-p_)
    F  = (k*x - d*v) / m # spring force
    v  = v + F * dt # update velocity
    p_ = p_ + v * dt # update dragged position

    print p_ # values oscillate and eventually stabilize to p
```

This works great for position. By changing `k`,`d` and `m` I can get a snappier/heavier results and overall I'm satisfied with how it feels:

[image: A visual output my physics simulation]

Now I want to do the same thing with `quaternions`. Because I have no experience doing physics with `quaternions`, I went down the naive road and applied the same function with a few modifications to deal with `quaternion` flips and normalization.

```
# quaternion expressed as x,y,z,w
q_ = np.array([0., 0., 0., 1.]) # initial quaternion of the dragged object
q  = np.array([0.382683, 0., 0., 0.92388]) # quaternion to catch up to (equivalent to xyz euler rotation of 45,0,0 degrees)
v  = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.]) # angular velocity buffer (init speed is assumed to be 0)

# Euler Integration
n = 200
for i in xrange(n):
    
    # In a real life use case, q varies over time and q_ tries to catch up to it.
    # Test to see if q and q_ are flipped with a dot product (innder1d).
    # If so, negate q
    if inner1d(q,q_) < 0:
        q = np.negative(q)
    
    x  = (q-q_)
    F  = (k*x - d*v) / m # spring force
    v  = v + F * dt # update velocity
    q_ = q_ + v * dt # update dragged quaternion
    q_ /= inner1d(q_,q_) # normalize
    
    print q_ # values oscillate and eventually stabilize to q
```

And to my great surprise it gives me very decent results!

[image: quaternion version]

Because I went with my instinct, I am sure my solution is flawed (like if q and q_ are opposed) and that there is a correct/better way to achieve what I want.

## QUESTION:

What is the correct way to simulate spring forces on `quaternions` that takes into account (at minimum) the `mass` of the dragged object, a spring `stiffness` and a `damping factor`.

Actual python code would be greatly appreciated as I have great difficulty reading PhD papers :). Also for `quaternion` manipulations I usually refer to [Christoph Gohlke's excellent library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/code/transformations.py.html), but please feel free to use any others in your answer.

Comment: I suspect you are ahead of most us when it comes to using quaternions with numpy.

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly find `v`, but `x` should probably be found with the [multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22167097/320036), and `q_` should probably be stepped using [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Quaternion_Slerp).

Comment: This is awesome; I think you've accidentally stumbled on a fantastic fast numerical approximation for quaternion oscillators.

Answer (score 6):

"Better" will be pretty subjective here actually.

You're kind of getting away with murdering the concept of quaternions, because your step size and displacements are small.  Depending on your application, that might actually be ok (game engines often exploit tricks like this to make real-time calculations easier) but if your goal is accuracy, or you want to increase your step size and not get unstable results, you'll need to use quaternions as they are meant to be used.

As @z0r explained in the comments, since quaternions transform rotations by multiplication, the "difference" between them is the multiplicative inverse - basically, quaternion division.

```
qinv = quaternion_inverse(q)  # Using Gohlke's package 
x = quaternion_multiply(q_, qinv)
```

Now, much as for small `theta`, `theta =~ sin(theta)`, this `x` is not very different from the result of subtraction as long as the difference is small.  Abusing "small angle theorems" like this is used often in simulations of all types, but it is important to know when you're breaking them and what limitations it puts on your model.

Accelerations and velocities still add, so I think this still works:

```
F  = (k*x - d*v) / m 
v  = v + F * dt
```

Compose the unit rotations

```
q_ = quaternion_multiply(q_, unit_vector(v * dt)) # update dragged quaternion
```

Once again, for small angles (i.e. `dt` is small compared to velocity), the sum and the product are very close.

Then normalize as before, if necessary.

```
q_ = unit_vector(q_)
```

I think that should work, but will be a bit slower than your previous version, and may have very similar results.

Answer (score 1):

So I've been working on this problem for quite a while, and while I don't have a solution for python, I do have a solution in luau. The math should pretty easy to convert from one language to another, however I couldn't account for mass but you should be able to achieve the same behaviour with just speed / damping.

The key point is to store the current rotation as a quaternion and the angular velocity as a rotation vector (i.e. compact axis angles), as this will allow the angular velocity to exceed 180 degrees/second.

I have the full source available on [Github](https://github.com/probablytukars/LuaQuaternion) with an accompanying [documentation](https://probablytukars.github.io/LuaQuaternion/) site.

However, as a summary you do the following:

Create a Quaternion spring object, the object should have the following fields:

- clock - a function which returns the current unix time in ms
- time - which stores the unix time of when it was last updated
- rotation - the current rotation as a quaternion
- velocity - the velocity of the spring, as a [rotation vector](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/cps274/fall13/notes/rodrigues.pdf)
- target - the target rotation of the spring (as a quaternion)
- damping - the damping of the spring as a number
- speed - the speed of the spring as a number

```lua
local QuaternionSpring = {_type = "QuaternionSpring"}

function QuaternionSpring.new(initial: Quaternion, damping: number, speed: number, clock: () -> number)
    initial = initial or Quaternion.identity
    damping = damping or 1
    speed = speed or 1
    clock = clock or os.clock
    
    return setmetatable({
        _clock = clock;
        _time = clock();
        _position = initial;
        _velocity = Vector3.new();
        _target = initial;
        _damping = damping;
        _speed = speed;
    }, QuaternionSpring)
end
```

Then you will need to create a function which handles when fields are indexed for getting the value (some languages offer this feature, some do not, so adjust as needed), aka a getter function.

First you need to check if the index is a method call, and if so return the function, then for position indexing it's just returning the position by calling the update spring method with the current clock time. For velocity its the same. For all of the other indexes, you can just return the stored field.

```lua
function QuaternionSpring:__index(index)
    if QuaternionSpring[index] then
        return QuaternionSpring[index]
    elseif index == "Position" or index == "p" then
        local position, _ = self:_positionVelocity(self._clock())
        return position
    elseif index == "Velocity" or index == "v" then
        local _, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(self._clock())
        return velocity
    elseif index == "Target" or index == "t" then
        return self._target
    elseif index == "Damping" or index == "d" then
        return self._damping
    elseif index == "Speed" or index == "s" then
        return self._speed
    elseif index == "Clock" then
        return self._clock
    else
        error(string.format(ERROR_FORMAT, tostring(index)), 2)
    end
end
```

Then you'll need a setter function, this will set the fields and update the spring as necessary. For pretty much all indexes, this means you'll need to call the spring update function which will return both position and velocity which you should set the position and fields to, except when position and velocity are the fields being updated, in that case, set the field in question to the given value, but only after calling update. Then update the target field, and set the time field to the time given by the clock.

```lua
function QuaternionSpring:__newindex(index, value)
    local now = self._clock()
    if index == "Position" or index == "p" then
        local _, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = value
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._time = now
    elseif index == "Velocity" or index == "v" then
        local position, _ = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = value
        self._time = now
    elseif index == "Target" or index == "t" then
        local position, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._target = value
        self._time = now
    elseif index == "Damping" or index == "d" then
        local position, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._damping = value
        self._time = now
    elseif index == "Speed" or index == "s" then
        local position, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._speed = value < 0 and 0 or value
        self._time = now
    elseif index == "Clock" then
        local position, velocity = self:_positionVelocity(now)
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._clock = value
        self._time = value()
    else
        error(string.format(ERROR_FORMAT, tostring(index)), 2)
    end
end
```

One thing you might note is that the time field is only updated when a field is set, not when a field is retrieved, this is important for the spring to work properly.

And now for the magic, the update function. This will calculate some delta time relative values which will then be used to update the spring.

The basic structure of updating the spring is as follows:

1. Calculate a pull quaternion, which is slerped from the current rotation to the target rotation using some pull value (which is relative to delta time).
2. Calculate the new position by integrating this pull quaternion by the current velocity and some push value (which is relative to delta time).
3. Calculate the difference between the current rotation and target rotation, and convert this to axis angles format
4. Convert the axis angles format to a rotation vector and multiply this rotation vector by some velocity push factor (which is relative to delta time)
5. Calculate the velocity decay by multiplying the current velocity by some velocity decay factor (which is relative to delta time)
6. Calculate the new velocity by adding the velocity vector calculated in step 4 with the decay vector calculated in step 5
7. Return the new position and new velocity

This is what that looks like:

```lua
function QuaternionSpring:_positionVelocity(now)
    local currentRotation = self._position
    local currentVelocity = self._velocity
    local targetRotation = self._target
    local dampingFactor = self._damping
    local speed = self._speed
    
    local deltaTime = speed * (now - self._time)
    local dampingSquared = dampingFactor * dampingFactor
    
    local angFreq, sinTheta, cosTheta
    if dampingSquared < 1 then
        angFreq = math.sqrt(1 - dampingSquared)
        local exponential = math.exp(-dampingFactor * deltaTime) / angFreq
        cosTheta = exponential * math.cos(angFreq * deltaTime)
        sinTheta = exponential * math.sin(angFreq * deltaTime)
    elseif dampingSquared == 1 then
        angFreq = 1
        local exponential = math.exp(-dampingFactor * deltaTime)
        cosTheta, sinTheta = exponential, exponential * deltaTime
    else
        angFreq = math.sqrt(dampingSquared - 1)
        local angFreq2 = 2 * angFreq
        local u = math.exp((-dampingFactor + angFreq) * deltaTime) / angFreq2
        local v = math.exp((-dampingFactor - angFreq) * deltaTime) / angFreq2
        cosTheta, sinTheta = u + v, u - v
    end
    
    local pullToTarget = 1 - (angFreq * cosTheta + dampingFactor * sinTheta)
    local velPosPush = sinTheta / speed
    local velPushRate = speed * sinTheta
    local velocityDecay = angFreq * cosTheta - dampingFactor * sinTheta
    
    local posQuat = currentRotation:Slerp(targetRotation, pullToTarget)
    local newPosition = posQuat:Integrate(currentVelocity, velPosPush)
    
    local difQuat = currentRotation:Difference(targetRotation)
    local axis, angle = difQuat:ToAxisAngle()
    local velPush = (axis * angle) * velPushRate
    local velDecay = currentVelocity * velocityDecay
    
    local newVelocity = velPush + velDecay
    
    return newPosition, newVelocity
end
```

A note on some specific implementations in this:

Slerp:

```lua
local function Slerp(q0: Quaternion, q1: Quaternion, alpha: number): Quaternion
    q0 = Normalize(q0)
    q1 = Normalize(q1)

    local dot = Dot(q0, q1)

    if dot < 0 then
        q0 = unm(q0)
        dot = -dot
    end

    if dot >= 1 then
        return Normalize(Add(q0, Mul(Sub(q1, q0), alpha)))
    end

    local theta0 = math.acos(dot)
    local sinTheta0 = math.sin(theta0)

    local theta = theta0 * alpha
    local sinTheta = math.sin(theta)

    local s0 = math.cos(theta) - dot * sinTheta / sinTheta0
    local s1 = sinTheta / sinTheta0
    return Normalize(Add(Mul(s0, q0), Mul(s1, q1)))
end
```

Integrate:

```lua
local function Integrate(q0: Quaternion, rate: Vector3, timestep: number): Quaternion
    q0 = Normalize(q0)
    
    local rotationVector = (rate * timestep)
    local rotationMag = rotationVector.Magnitude
    if rotationMag > 0 then
        local axis = rotationVector / rotationMag
        local angle = rotationMag
        local q1 = fromAxisAngle(axis, angle)
        return Normalize(Mul(q0, q1))
    else
        return q0
    end
end
```

Difference:

```lua
local function Difference(q0: Quaternion, q1: Quaternion): Quaternion
    if Dot(q0, q1) < 0 then
        q0 = unm(q0)
    end
    return Mul(Inverse(q0), q1)
end
```

I know this answer was quite long, but hopefully this helps someone else in the future who also wants to know how a quaternion spring works. I know this question is quite old but this problem has been my worst enemy for the past 3 months and I don't want anyone else to be stuck in that same position :)

Answer (score 0):

On the question "What is the correct way to simulate spring forces on quaternions", the reply is to write down the potential energy properly.

1. The quaternion gives you the orientation of the object via the operation

   ```
   orientation = vector_part(q_ r q_*)
   ```

   where the star denotes conjugation and r is a fixed orientation (say "unit vector along z" for instance, it must be unique in your system for all objects). The multiplication of q_, r and q_* is assumed to be "quaternion multiplication".
2. define the energy function with this orientation, for instance

   ```
   energy = dot_product(orientation, unit_z)
   ```
3. take "minus the derivative" of the energy with respect to the quaternion and you will have the force to apply to the system.

Your current code does a "damped oscillator in quaternion space" that might be a good solution to your problem, but it is not a spring force on an object :-)

PS: too long for a comment, I hope it helps.
PS2: I didn't use a direct code for the problem above because (i) I didn't find it easy to just read in the library documentation above and (ii) the first part of the problem is to do the math/physics.